# Parsing data from cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I've been trying to use the "net time" utility in order to get the time of another machine on the network (I can't use existing windows services for various reasons). It is getting the correct data but is not saving it to variables correctly. I've written a bit of code that shows what I am running into.

```
::@ECHO off

for /f "tokens=1-2,6,7,8" %%i in ('net time \\A13027-07T9') do (
if "%%i %%j"=="Current time"( set d=%%k set t=%%l set AP=%%m)   
)

echo %d%
echo %t%
echo %AP%

PAUSE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to cram 3 `set` commands onto one line.  You either need to separate them with `&` or put each on its own line.

As Stephan points out, using `find` can make your code a bit cleaner looking as well.

Anyway, proper indentation and code formatting helps avoid simple mistakes like this.

```js
@ECHO off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=6-8" %%i in ('net time \\A13027-07T9 ^| find "Current"') do (
    set "d=%%i"
    set "t=%%j"
    set "AP=%%k"
)

echo %d%
echo %t%
echo %AP%

PAUSE
```

Or if you prefer not to use `find` and want to keep your `set`s on the same line:

```js
@ECHO off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1-2,6-8" %%i in ('net time \\A13027-07T9') do (
    if /i "%%i %%j"=="Current time" ( set "d=%%k" & set "t=%%l" & set "AP=%%m" )
)

echo %d%
echo %t%
echo %AP%

PAUSE
```

Personally, I find the first version more readable.

Answer (score 2):

filtering your data helps:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2,6,7,8" %%i in ('net time \\A13027-07T9^|find "Current time"') do (
```

the complete working script (adapted to my german windows):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-2,6,7,8" %%i in ('net time \\AkoyaD^|find "Aktuelle Zeit"') do (
    set d=%%k 
    set t=%%l 
    set AP=%%m
)
echo %d%
echo %t%
echo %AP%
PAUSE
```

gives me:

```
07.04.2015
21:43:54.
ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

the "Echo ist ausgeschaltet" is, because in german time, there is no AM/PM.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help the issue.